# Find all positive integers x such that $x^4-8x+16$ is a full square

Tags: polynomials, square-numbers, quartics

> Find all positive integers x such that $x^4-8x+16$ is a full square.

I presented it as $(x-4)^2+x^4-x^2$ and found that $x = +1$ satisfy the condition. Then I equalized it $(x-4)^2+x^4-x^4=a^2+2ab+b^2$ then $a=x-4$ and nothing else happened. Help prove that there are no more solutions or find the rest of the solutions

Comment: Did you try $x=2$?

Comment: It's worth writing it as $(x^2-4)^2+ 8(x^2-x)$

Comment: Also, $x=-1,0$ are not positive integers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yeah sure

Comment: Seems like all integers $x$ (including negative integers and zero) such that $x^4-8x+16$ is a perfect square are $x=-3,-1,0,1,2$.

Comment: Do you mean "perfect square" instead of "full square" ?

Comment: @Peter Same thing, methinks -- perfect, complete, full, are synonyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x \ge 3$, we have:

$$x^4-8x+16=x^4-8(x-2)<x^4$$

and

$$x^4-8x+16-(x^2-1)^2=2(x-2)^2+7 > 0$$

Therefore $x^4>x^4-8x+16>(x^2-1)^2$ for $x\geq 3$ (it is bounded by two consecutive perfect squares).

It remains to check $x=1$ and $x=2$, which are indeed solutions.

Comment: You beat me by a minute, and your answer is good; +1

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

For $x>2$, $(x^2-1)^2<x^4-8x+16<(x^2)^2$.

Comment: J.W. Tanner, Perfection :)